# Backup software with dedup, remote/cloud and BMR option

Tags: windows, backup

I am currently looking for backup software with special intended usuage and requirements.

The backup scenario is that we want to backup several branchoffice/customer networks with about a dozen users including both Windows clients and servers, and manage that centrally.

The idea is that all clients should have a backup agent with option to backup both to a local network backup server, and also through the internet to our cloud servers in case we need redundance.

It is also important to have deduplication as there will be many similar windows clients/servers, and as we pay for the cloud storage it is important to keep the storage use as small as possible.

It is also important with BMR (bare metal recovery) to be able to do a full restore on a corrupted computer that preferably has awareness of different hardware as well.

Ideally a computer should be able to crash, and then possible to perform a BMR-recovery directly through the internet from our cloud backup servers.
Ideally a backup client should also be able to back up directly to the cloud without mandatory local backup server.

We have tried Arcserve backup that is good but unfortunately seems server-centric and it does not seem to be possible for an agent to backup directly to the internet cloud, but a local backup server is required that in turn can be replicated to the cloud.

I have also started to investigate Storagecraft Shadowprotect, but my impression is that it is weak on deduplication which is bad as we need the option to cut down cloud storage.

To reiterate, a backup software where the agent from different offices/customers can backup directly through the internet to our cloud backupserver, have good deduplication and also able to perform BMR by pulling the image directly from our cloud backup server.

It is strongly preferred to be Windows servers, and subscription fees for client licenses are fine. There is real no price tag involved, as good and stable functionality can justify a higher price.

Comment: i don't use them myself, therefore just a comment: i guess [BackupPC](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/) or [UrBackup](https://www.urbackup.org/) could be very interesting. maybe [Bacula](http://blog.bacula.org/) or [Amanda](http://www.amanda.org/) is also worth a look...

Answer (score 1):

**I am affiliated with this company**

Try [CloudBerry managed backup service](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/managed-online-backup-service-amazon-s3-azure.aspx).

It comes with the **central management and monitoring** functionality, with:

- Support Windows Server 2003/2008/2012 , Windows XP/Vista/7/8 , Linux,  Mac
- Doesn't require space on the local drive  back up to the cloud    directly
- Restore from USB Flash directly from the cloud
- Back up all  or selected volumes
- File Level Recovery
- Restore to a dissimilar    hardware
- Restore to Hyper-V or VMware
- Restore as  Amazon EC2 (DR)
- Restore as  Azure VM (DR)

Comment: Thank you, is this however just a cloud-based solution? There is a need for customer to have a local backup-server only, or hybrid-solution with local backup server replicated to the cloud.

Comment: We support local backup to NAS, local and external drive. Check out the link below for more info http://www.cloudberrylab.com/blog/local-backup-with-block-level-encryption-compression-versioning/   The hybrid backup that will simultaneously back up to local storage and to the cloud is on our short term roadmap. Currently you will need to set up two backup plans, one to the local storage and the other one to the cloud.

Comment: I am afraid that global deduplication is a mandatory requirement, but I can modify the initial requirements to settle for global deduplication, so all suggestions of solutions that support that are welcome.

Comment: We have a separate product called Data Dedup Server and you are welcome to try it out at http://www.cloudberrylab.com/dedup

You can download the Getting Started Guide at
http://www.cloudberrylab.com/download/CloudBerry_Dedup_Getting_Started.pdf

It is fully integrated with the managed backup

Answer (score 1):

Try http://mattmahoney.net/dc/zpaq.html
An open source masterpiece that includes hash-based block deduplication, several compression algorithms, cloud integration and has back-guards compatibility granted.